# how to count the numbers entered by the user

Tags: java, loops

I need to count the numbers entered by the user but i cant figure it out. all it can do is count the digits instead of the numbers entered. Im not allowed to use array, only looping.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int count = 0;
int num = in.nextInt();
int a = in.nextInt();

while(num > 0 && a > 0)
{
    num /= 10;
    a /= 10;
    count ++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

*input: 2 2165 Expected output:2*

Comment: Why should your code work?

Comment: You _wrote code specifically_ to count the digits.  Why did you do that, if counting the digits wasn't your goal?

Comment: @KevinAnderson yes, i know but i dont know how to make it count in numbers thats why i make it to count numbers for now.

Comment: Do `in.nextInt()` inside a loop, so that you can input (and _count_) an arbitrary number of input numbers.  But now you have to decide a way to signal that there are no more numbers to be counted (i.e.: when to stop looping).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will definitely not count numbers.

This one definitely will:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int count = 0;
int num;

while(in.hasNextInt())
{
    num = in.nextInt();
    num /= 10;
    count ++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

This will count all entered numbers till a non-number is entered.

Comment: what is ".hasNextInt" mean ?

Comment: It checks if the input stream has another Integer. You can find the documentation for it here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider marking it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: your code works, but apparently the two other test is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use loops for that. your code is counting digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int count = 0;
int inNumber = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter -1 to stop");

while(inNumber != -1)
{
       inNumber = in.nextInt();
       count ++;
}

System.out.println("Count: "+count);
```

Jonny, once the user inputs -1, loop exits and it displays the count.

Comment: Don't you need to ask for input inside the loop?

Comment: Thanks @NomadMaker for mentioning... I had modified the code